# C Need to assign char f[500]; char *k[500]; one to another.

Tags: c

So I have a program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char kazkas;
    char f[500];
    char *k[500];
    int x=0;
    int o = 0;
    int i=0;
    memset(f, 0, 255);
    memset(k, 0, 255);
    int len = 0;
    int par = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp=fopen("tekstas.txt", "r"))== NULL){
        printf("failo \n ddd \t ddd");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
            kazkas = fgetc(fp);
            while(!feof(fp))
            {
                kazkas = fgetc(fp);

                len = strlen(f);

                f[len + 1] = f[len];

                f[len] = kazkas;

                if(kazkas == '\t')
                {
                    k[i] = f;
                    i++;
                    memset(f, 0, 255);

                    par++;

                }
            }
    }

    printf("%s", k[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Don't look at the whole code, you don't need it. The thing is in

```
        if(kazkas == '\t')
        {
            k[i] = f;
            i++;
            memset(f, 0, 255);

            par++;

        }
```

When I find a '\t' symbol I want to transfer all my f (the thing I've been reading to) to my k[i] array and set f to zero so I could scan the other paragraph.. The k[i] = f; doesn't work though if I wrote k[0] = "SOMETHING"; It would work.. What is the problem? How should I transfer my f into k[i] ?

Comment: Yes, I malloc'ed the memory to k[i] and now everything works fine. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memset(f, 0, 255);` changes the value at f to 0 for the first 255 characters, and k[i] points to the same location as f, so therefore k[i] points at those characters.  I'm assuming you want to have f point at a new location, in which case you should replace that with:

```
f = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
```

You could also use strcpy to copy f to k[i] instead, as Tu Bui suggested, though you would still need to clear f afterward, presumably with memset.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to allocate a new block of memory for `k[i]` to point to. As you have it `f` only ever points to one location that is 500 `char` long and keeps getting reused. To avoid writing over the data you attempted to store, try something like:

```
if (kazkas == '\t')
{
    char *new = malloc(sizeof f);
    memcpy(new, f, sizeof f);
    k[i] = new;
    //f has been safely copied over and can be re-used
}
```

Because this memory is `malloc`d, you'll need to make sure to `free` it when you aren't using it any more.

Edit: If your data is null-terminated strings, you can use `strlen(f) + 1` instead of `sizeof f` and `strncpy` instead of `memcpy`. But my example will work regardless of what data is stored in your char array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
k[i]=(char*)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
strcpy(k[i],f);
```

You need to allocate memory to k[i] before you can use it to store a string (in your case it is the paragraph).

Comment: Missing +1 for terminating 0, and superfluous use of `sizeof(char)` which is 1 by standard.